# lower bounds for growth of a sequence

Tags: co.combinatorics, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Suppose I have an (integer valued, but it probably does not matter) *monotonically increasing* function $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R},$ which satisfies 
$$\sum_{i=1}^n f(i) < f(2 n).$$ What can we say about the speed of growth of this function?

Comment: Roughly speaking, at least $e^{c\log^2 n}$ with some particular $c$ depending on $2$.

Comment: @fedja Could you elaborate?

Comment: You mean why that growth can happen or why you cannot go up slower?

Comment: @fedja Both of those, and  what the most elegant way of getting there is...

Comment: OK, but I need to think a bit about "the most elegant way" :-)

Comment: @fedja Thanks! Enlightenment always appreciated...

Comment: How much precision do you want? Showing the estimate $f(n)\ge \delta(c)e^{c\log^2n}$ with any $c<\frac{1}{2\log 2}$ is just trivial induction, but if you want more accuracy, I'll need to really think a bit.

Comment: @fedja Ideally, as much as precision as possible. The question actually comes from this: I am teaching combinatorics, and this inequality is true (and not hard to show ) for the partition function, purely combinatorially. So, I am curious how much more one needs to show to get to the true order of growth (or at least to get the right power in the exponent).

Comment: Erm... But you have no chance to get anywhere near $e^{c\sqrt n}$ anyway, so what's the point of getting more precision here? Am I missing anything?

Comment: Also, if you want just the lower bound $e^{c\sqrt n}$ for $p(n)$, choose $m$ such that $1+2+\dots+m$ is slightly below $n/2$ and for each number from $1$ to $m$ decide whether to include it or not independently filling the remainder with one big chunk. That is as elementary as it can get. The upper bound of the same kind is a bit trickier but also possible. I just don't remember it now but can try to recall it if you are really interested.

Comment: @fedja No, for this question it is more a question of how much information one can get from the inequality - of course, it does not help with partitions... Your partition argument is very nice!

Comment: Do you want me to try to recall an elementary proof of the upper bound, or the generating function argument is OK to use in your class? :-)

Comment: @fedja That would be great (it is not a question of it being OK, more of aesthetic satisfaction...

Comment: Done. Not sure that it is the *most* elementary bound, but we can work on that if you feel like it is still too hard for the students. Of course, the generating function approach is also rather elementary and gives the right exponent (if one can integrate properly), so I do not really see much gain here.

Comment: Let me give a very rough argument that gives the same bound: consider the case $n=2^{k+1}$. Then $f(2^{k+1})>2^kf(2^k)$.  Write $x_k=f(2^k)$ so this gives $x_{k+1}>x_k+k\log 2$ or $x_k\gtrsim k^2/2\log 2$. Changing coordinates, you obtain the same rough bound as before.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas Should be $f(2^{k+2})>2^kf(2^k)$ really, shouldn't it?

Comment: @IgorRivin you mean usual Euler's partition function $p(n)$? Then this is too weak bound. I think, this relation defines the number of partitions onto powers of 2 (we have exactly $f(k)$ partitions of $2n$ in which the sum of even parts equals $2k$, other parts are 1's. Probably, we need a summand $f(0)=1$ on the left.) This was the subject of the problem IMO1997.6, you may easily google many discussions of it.

Comment: @fedja Yes I agree this is just a heuristic argument. I'm assuming that $f$ grows much slower than exponentially so that the sum is roughly comparable to the number of terms multiplied by its last term.

Comment: @FedorPetrov Thanks, I will take a look!

Comment: There is an easy elementary upper bound of $P_\sqrt{n}(n)^2 \le {n+\sqrt{n} \choose \sqrt{n}}^2 $ since each partition of $n$ is determined by the first $\sqrt{n}$ parts and the parts of size at most $\sqrt{n}$ and the number of partitions of at most $n$ into $\sqrt{n}$ parts is (much) lower than the number of compositions of n into $\sqrt{n}$ parts. You can do better by using that parts number $2^i$ through $2^{i+1}$ can be at most $n/2^i$, which gives a bound that is $\exp(c\sqrt{n})$. This generalizes to plane partitions and higher.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is the trivial part where I'm pretty sure that the way is close to the most elegant requested:

$f(n)=e^{c\log^2 n}$ with $c=\frac 1{2\log 2}$ satisfies the inequality.
Indeed, 
$$
f(2n)=e^{c\log^2 n+2c\log 2\log n+c\log^22}\ge f(n)n\ge \sum_{i=1}^nf(i)
$$
Here is the crude lower bound $f(n)\ge \delta f(1)e^{c\log^2 n}$ with any $c<\frac 1{2\log 2}$ and $\delta=\delta(c)>0$.

For any finite number of terms the estimate holds if we choose $\delta>0$ small enough. Suppose that we have the estimate up to $2n-1$ with sufficiently large $n$. Then
$$
f(2n)\ge \delta\sum_{0\le j<\varepsilon n}e^{c\log^2(n-j)}\ge\varepsilon ne^{c\log^2 n+2c\log(1-\varepsilon)\log n}
\\
=e^{c\log^2 n+\log n(1+2c\log(1-\varepsilon))+\log\varepsilon}\ge e^{c\log^2(2n+1)}
$$
provided that $c<\frac 1{2\log 2}$, $\varepsilon<\varepsilon(c)$, and $n\ge N(c,\varepsilon)$,
so we are fine up to $2n+1$.

I wouldn't call this "elegant" and it is way too crude (we can actually get an asymptotic behavior; then there will be a correction logarithmic term in the exponent, etc.), but I'll leave it here for now.

***Elementary upper bound for $p(n)$***.

First, choose how many different numbers you want in your partition (can choose any $k\le \sqrt{2n}$, so $\sqrt{2n}$ choices here.

Next choose the actual numbers you want to use. They should sum up to $\le n$, so choose $k$ points between $1$ and $n$ and view your numbers as the differences between successive points (including 0); if two of those coincide, discard the configuration, otherwise note that each set appeared $k!$ times, so we have ${n\choose k}/k!\le \frac{n^k}{(k!)^2}$ options here.

Now, choose the multiplicities so that the sum is $\le n$. Obviously, the worst case scenario is when you have $1,2,\dots,k$. If your students don't mind elementary geometry, just associate with each integer solution of $a_1+2a_2+\dots+ka_k$ a parallelepiped in $\mathbb R^k$ of size $1\times 2\times\dots\times k$ with the corner at $(a_1,2a_2,\dots, ka_k)$. Since $1+2+\dots +k\le n$, they are all contained in the simplex $x_1+\dots+x_k\le 2n$, $x_j\ge 0$, so the volumetric bound gives $\frac{(2n)^k}{(k!)^2}$.

Now all we need to show is that $\frac{n^k}{(k!)^2}=\left[\frac{(\sqrt n)^k}{k!}\right]^2\le e^{2\sqrt n}$.

If your students are afraid of $k$-dimensional geometry or ignorant of the series expansion of $e^x$, let me know and I'll try to circumvent both :-)

Answer (score 3):

This is an extended remark. It is easy to see that there is a minorant $g(n)$ of
all such increasing sequences with fixed $f(1)$: put $g(1)=f(1)$,
$$g(2^{n+1})=\sum_{1}^n g(k),$$
and $g(k)=g(2^n)$ for $2^n<k<2^{n+1}$. These conditions define $g$ uniquely,
and we have $f(k)\geq g(k)$ for all $k$. The equation for $g$ suggests that we consider the continuous analog:
$$F(2x)=\int_0^xF(t)dt, \quad\mbox{or}\quad F'(x)=(1/2)F(x/2).$$
Adding the initial condition $F(0)=1$ we obtain the unique entire solution
$$F(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^{-n(n+1)/2}\frac{z^n}{n!},$$
the famous entire function which Alan Sokal calls the "deformed exponential". The growth rate of this $F$ is easy to find with the standard
methods of the theory of entire functions: it is $\log F(x)\sim \exp (c\log^2x)$, where
$c=1/(2\log 2)$. (The growth of $F$ is like the maximal term in its Taylor series. In our case this maximal term dominates the whole sum).

Ref. A. Sokal, Some wonderful conjectures...  http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~pjc/csgnotes/sokal/

Comment: That's a nice argument!